# Cordova add text box into alert

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, cordova

Friends, I need to add text box into alert view in phonegap/ cordova application.

[image]

I use the following link tutorial for creating two buttons in alert view. `http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html` but i can't add the text-box into that. Actually I have to send email id to the server when user forgot the password. Is there another way to do that thing... plz share...

Comment: A code snippet would be great!

Comment: you just create one demo using given link and and add text box into that...

Comment: ... you want me to help you with your problem and then you tell me to make my own example? Wrong way, but here's a litle hint from me for you. The actual Cordova Version is 3.5 https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/blob/master/doc/index.md

Comment: cool down, actually i am new in cordova and i just want to add text box into alert box/view as per image and i provide one link also, which is is smiler to my requirement. If you satisfy my these answer then go ahed.

Comment: thanks i got my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this code

```
function onPrompt(results) {
alert("You selected button number " + results.buttonIndex + " and entered " + results.input1);
}

navigator.notification.prompt(
'Please enter your name',  // message
onPrompt,                  // callback to invoke
'Registration',            // title
['Ok','Exit'],             // buttonLabels
'Jane Doe'                 // defaultText
);
```

Comment: Fine, that my link has helped you!